# Laravel Nova: how to display image from binary string?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I save PNG's binary content in database.
I want display this PNG's on page without temporary save file on disk.
I think need generate img tag like `<img src="data:image/png;base64,......`

But I do not understand how it is better to implement it and what type of field to take as a basis.

```
            Image::make('Image')->displayUsing(function($item) {
                $mime_type = 'image/png';
                return 'data: ' . $mime_type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($item);
            }),
```

But Laravel Nova generated:

```
<img src="http://172.18.0.3/storage/data: image/png;base64,......" class="rounded-full w-8 h-8" style="object-fit: cover;">
```

Added unnecessary `http://172.18.0.3/storage/`and rounded class.

How to prevent it adding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Work code for Laravel Nova 2.0.1:

```
Image::make('QRCode', 'qrcode')->thumbnail(function($value, $disk) {
    return 'data: image/png;base64,' . $value;
})->preview(function($value, $disk) {
    return 'data: image/png;base64,' . $value;
})->displayUsing(function($value) {
return  base64_encode($value);})
```

Also need remove `rounded-full` from `field.thumbnailUrl?t("img",{staticClass:"rounded-full w-8 h-8",` in file public\vendor\nova\app.js

Answer (score 2):

Override `thumbnail` & `preview` for image url

Try below code snippet

```
Image::make('Image')->thumbnail(function($value, $disk) {
        return 'data: image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($value);
    })->preview(function($value, $disk) {
        return 'data: image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($value);
    }),
```

Comment: Do not work in Laravel Nova 2.0.1:

```{
    "message": "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "/var/www/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php",
    "line": 75,```

Also do not work if return `''` instead `'data: image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($value)`.

Wrong way....