# Nova Laravel Show Image

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am new to Laravel Nova Framework. I have stored image using image upload field. I am using concept of blob to same image.

Application Model (Name, Description, Image) -> ApplicationAttachment -> Blob

How to show the image in resource page?

I am trying to use following code.

```
Avatar::make('Photo')->thumbnail(function () {
        return "image_url";
    })->onlyOnDetail(),
```

Here, inside thumbnail, I want to replace static url with my dynamic. For that, I want to get current model inside thumbnail function. But it shows me undefined.

I tried to get like $model.

- Laravel version 6
- Nova version 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Nova: how to display image from binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852952/laravel-nova-how-to-display-image-from-binary-string)

Comment: @WahyuKristianto
No , I want to get my current model inside thumbnail callback function.